# Get legs length from right angle and hypotenuse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Here I have a 2 points. $A$ (lat,lng) and $B$ (lat,lng), this two point is hypotenuse of right triangle.

How I can get legs length if I know angle, hypotenuse and these points?

Answer (score 1):

Make equations like:

1) $$\frac{\sin(\text{angle})}{\sin(90^{\circ}-\text{angle})} = \frac{\text{firstLeg}}{\text{secondLeg}}$$

2) $$\text{firstLeg}^2 + \text{secondLeg}^2 = \text{hypotenuse}^2$$

Comment: I dont know angle, I just know that I have right angle triangle and hypotenuse

Comment: so then it could be an infinite number of different triangles :) unless you have some more information, like the legs are both the same length or something...

Comment: yes I have First point(lat,lng) and Second point(lat,lng)

Comment: as I understood it's the end points of a hypotenuse?

Comment: yes but every point have latitude and longitude